# javascript : Sort array with number and alphabetical

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm looking for a way to sort an array with words and numbers on each array by highest number

E.g.

```
'jimmy=40'
'bobby=100'
'cattie=30'
'marrie=50'
'jonny=60'
```

turns into

```
'bobby=100'
'jonny=60'
'marrie=50'
'jimmy=40'
'cattie=30'
```

Is there any solutions for this problem ?

Comment: Strip the number from the string, parse it into an actual number and compare them. Shouldn't be too complicated to solve.

Comment: Split string based on =. Use custom comparator to sort them.

Comment: What have you tried to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the array items with `=` and compare the number part inside [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) event handler function:

```js
var arr = ['jimmy=40', 'bobby=100', 'cattie=30', 'marrie=50', 'jonny=60'];
function sortData(data){
  return data.sort(function(a, b){
    return b.split('=')[1] - a.split('=')[1];
  });
}

console.log(sortData(arr));
```

Comment: It doesn't work. So in my case, I get 1 JSON type data, I stringify them and then use split(",") to make an array, then i use your method to sort them. But it doesn't change anything

Comment: @BobMarky, if the array is having the proper data, then the solution should work:)

Comment: I'm sorry, it worked! I just use : instead of =. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in three steps.

- First **split** the array items by equal sign.
- **Sort** the array based on number.
- Again **join** array items by equal sign.

```js
let data = ["jimmy=40", "bobby=100", "cattie=30", "marrie=50", "jonny=60"];
let ret = data
  .map((x) => (x = x.split("=")))
  .sort((x, y) => y[1] - x[1])
  .map((x) => x.join("="));
console.log(ret);
```